# No ModelState available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

So I'm doing a course that was back with .netcore 1.0, however, I programming it know with .net core 2.0. however, when checking my 'model' there isn't any modelstate like in the course. When i google it I get many answers that it's still in .net core 2.0 even from the microsoft doc when I added modelbinding a checked in modelstatdictionary ther isn't just a property or method called 'isvalid'

this is my current piece of code: (i want it to put in my if block)

```
    [HttpPost("api/trips")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Trip theTrip)
    { 
        if ()
        {

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Any ideas why? do I need to add services or don't I have web API or something?

Comment: It's extremely difficult to understand what you're asking here. What exactly are you trying to put in your `if` condition? What have you tried? You're looking for a method called 'IsValid' in what class?

Comment: Does you controller inherit from `Controller` class? That's where the `ModelState` is inherited from. Please note that's not a requirement to inherit your controllers from that base class in `.net core`  anymore.

Comment: @karel tamayo wow thx man perfect i forgot to derive it from the controller class. So in my if block i have now ModelState.IsValid